# After restoring registry via RegBack, how to identify root cause

Tags: windows-10, windows-registry, bsod

I encountered a [**BAD_SYSTEM_CONFIG_INFO**](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/debugger/bug-check-0x74--bad-system-config-info) bug check and was able to recover the system by restoring the registry hives from the RegBack folder.

I backed up the "corrupted" hives before restoring the hive backups.

But now I'm trying to identify what in the old hives was causing the bug check.

Using [RegistryChangesView](https://www.nirsoft.net/utils/registry_changes_view.html) and looking only at the SYSTEM hive, I see >1000 differences.

**Main question:** Is there a way to pare this down to identify what entry/set of entries was causing the bug check and the system to fail to boot?

In other words, is there a defined set of registry keys that, if incorrect or corrupted could cause the BAD_SYSTEM_INFO bugcheck?

<s>**Side concern:** Is there anything to look out for now that I'm running a system where the files may be out of sync with the (up to 10 day) old registry?</s>

Comment: I find it a little amusing that the “put on hold” box says, “Avoid asking multiple distinct questions at once.” and you defend yourself by saying, “There are two … questions listed.”  But thank you for keeping your language civil and polite (even though I sense agitation / anger behind them). I agree that your questions are clear, objective, and answerable (although the second one is somewhat broad), so I’m voting to reopen (i.e., take off hold).

Comment: I went ahead and removed your meta commentary from your question.  I couldn’t justify a reopen vote with it being there.